# Highcharts, changing legend icon to represent image

Tags: javascript, highcharts, styling

I'm creating a stacked bar graph, and I was wondering if I could modify the legend so I would be able to place an image/icon instead of the default box.

Default look:

[image: Default look]

What I want it to look like:

[image: What I want it to look like]

Comment: can you please embed image into questions ?

Comment: I'm a new user, and I needed 10 points to embed the image

Answer (score 1):

There is no API that would allow inserting images instead of series symbols in legend. Quickest solution that comes to mind is to create custom legend inside a chart using `Renderer` (API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) or outside a chart using HTML elements. Other than that is it possible to extend `Highcharts` (How-to: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) and enable this additional feature.

Example with custom legend outside a chart: http://jsfiddle.net/hs941kka/